# Exclude file when bundle with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm try to exclude file from bundle file, by using webpack
I have a directory:

```
-- src
      --assets
           -- main.js
      --config
           -- config.js
```

In main.js, I have imported config.js

```
import * as envConfig from '../../config/config.js'
```

Here is the webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

var config = {
    entry: {
        main: './index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: '*.html',
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        },
        {
            from: './assets/images/*',
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        }
        ])
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /config/],
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|woff(2)?|ttf|eot|json)$/,
                use: 'url-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader?url=false"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    performance: { hints: false },
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

The thing is I want to exclude config.js out of the main.js, I don't want the content of config.js in the bundle file ( main.js)
but after build I still see its content.

Comment: Wouldn't your application fail if it didn't contain the config?

Comment: my application build with docker container, I have prepared the config in the container at the same location after build docker. 
in docker container: 
-- main.js
-- config/config.js
when run by using npm run dev: it will load file from src/config/config.js
I want when build docker. it will load from container , that why I want to exclude that file, 
is that the correct way ?

Comment: I don't think that works as webpack converts import statements to calls inside it's bundle. `../../config/config.js` would not just go to that path in a production bundle... But I could be wrong